# SQL - Check if date is in database

Tags: sql, date

I want to check if the date I set is no less than the dates in the table.
In the table I have following data.

```
id: 1
startDate: 2019-08-09
price: 30

id: 2
startDate: 2019-12-20
price: 20
```

I want to check if for example 2018-01-01 is in the price table. If not then dont show any output.
Another example is that if I set a price with 2019-11-19 it should show the id = 1.
hope u understand.

I have tried something like

```
 select * from wpiy_veosoft_crm_price where startDate <= '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59428998/edit) your post to include a tag for the specific database you're using. [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the maximum id whose date is less than the parameter, you can do:

```
select max(id) from wpiy_veosoft_crm_price where startDate <= ?
```

If you want the entire record:

```
select * from wpiy_veosoft_crm_price where startDate <= ? order by id desc limit 1
```

You might also want to sort by `startDate` rather than by `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id FROM wpiy_veosoft_crm_price where startDate < $1 ORDER BY startDate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

where $1 is a specific date.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft SQL Server it is
`select * from price_table where Format(startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2019-12-19'`